# How to tan a rabbit hide to make a fur and/or leather

Tags: hunting, tanning

I will go hunting rabbit in a few weeks and I'm planning to tan the hide, but I don't know how.also will be nice if it explains how to make soft leather as well; as I will have multiple hides

Comment: I think this question can be changed to 'How to tan an animal hide".  There are two basic processes one makes fur the other makes leather, you will want to clarify if you want the fur to remain on the hide when done.  If you want fur, then change the title to "How to tan a fur" or "How to prepare a fur"

Comment: Okay.im kind of a noob at this